# Issues when replacing dataset of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app which displays images from a website. The images all have different heights, and so do the views (viewholders) they are displayed in.

When applying a filter, the previous dataset (thus, the one that is currently visible) gets removed by directly clearing them from the Adapter. The adapter is notified that this happened with

```
final int removedSize = items.size();
items.clear();
notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, removedSize);
```

This makes the old items animate off the screen. When that animation has finished, I add the new dataset using

```
RecyclerView attachedView;

attachedView.getItemAnimator().isRunning(new RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener() { // Add a listener to listen when the new items should be added
            @Override
            public void onAnimationsFinished() {
                attachedView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        addPhotosList(objects);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, objects.size());                            
                        loading = false;
                        attachedView.requestLayout();
                    }
                },700);
            }
        });
```

This animates the added items. 
The strange thing is that I sometimes get gaps inside the RecyclerView as if the RecyclerView doesn't take the new dimensions of the ViewHolder into account when drawing all of the items. What's more is that some of the items are literally laid on top of each other and they flash into the foreground whenever they like. The items that are on top of the items that are placed in the right position are items that should be placed inside the gaps. They will not go back into the gap, but when manually investigating the item set, I noticed that they should be there.

The RecyclerView is the child of a SwipeRefreshLayout view, but I don't think that should be an issue.

Some of the parameters I've set to the RecyclerView:

```
recents.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recents.setHasFixedSize(false);
recents.setItemViewCacheSize(100);
```

Inside the layout file

```
android:animationCache="false"
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've already added a small delay of 0,7 seconds to make sure that all the animations are finished, but that doesn't seem to help very much.

ItemAnimator:

```
@Override
    public boolean animateAdd(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() != -8) { // ImageAdapter.ViewType.EMPTY = -8;
            if (viewHolder.getLayoutPosition() > lastAddAnimatedItem) {
                lastAddAnimatedItem++;
                runEnterAnimation((ImageListView) viewHolder, viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
                return false;
            }
        }
        lastAddAnimatedItem = -6;
        dispatchAddFinished(viewHolder);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateRemove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() != -8) { // ImageAdapter.ViewType.EMPTY = -8;
            if (viewHolder.getLayoutPosition() > lastRemoveAnimatedItem) {
                lastRemoveAnimatedItem++;
                runExitAnimation((ImageListView) viewHolder, viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
                return false;
            }
        }

        lastRemoveAnimatedItem = -6;
        dispatchRemoveFinished(viewHolder);
        return false;
    }

    private void runEnterAnimation(final ImageListView holder, int position) {
        final int screenHeight = Utils.getScreenHeight(holder.itemView.getContext());
        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(screenHeight + holder.itemView.getHeight());
        holder.itemView.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setStartDelay(150 + (20 * (position)))
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
                .setDuration(700)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        dispatchAddFinished(holder);
                    }
                })
                .start();
    }

    private void runExitAnimation(final ImageListView holder, int position) {
        final int screenHeight = Utils.getScreenHeight(holder.itemView.getContext());
        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(0);
        holder.itemView.animate()
                .translationY(-screenHeight - holder.itemView.getHeight())
                .setStartDelay(Math.abs(20 * (position)))
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
                .setDuration(700)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        dispatchRemoveFinished(holder);
                    }
                })
                .start();
    }
```

EDIT:

It appears that the **first** item after the **last visible** item that is on the screen is placed on the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting with this issue for over a week, but I found the solution:

Change runEnterAnimation to this:

```
private void runEnterAnimation(final ImageListView holder, int position) {
        final int screenHeight = Utils.getScreenHeight(holder.itemView.getContext());
        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(screenHeight);
        holder.itemView.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setStartDelay(150 + (20 * (position)))
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
                .setDuration(700)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        dispatchAddFinished(holder);
                        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(0f);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){
                        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(0f);
                    }
                })
                .start();
    }
```

Notice the new lines inside the onAnimationEnd and the onAnimationCancel callbacks, this makes sure that the translation of the item is always set to the desired translation that the animation was animating to.

Replace runExitAnimation with this:

```
private void runExitAnimation(final ImageListView holder, int position) {
        final int screenHeight = Utils.getScreenHeight(holder.itemView.getContext());
        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(0);
        holder.itemView.animate()
                .translationY(-screenHeight)
                .setStartDelay(Math.abs(20 * (position)))
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
                .setDuration(700)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        dispatchRemoveFinished(holder);
                        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(-screenHeight);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){
                        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(-screenHeight);
                    }
                })
                .start();
    }
```

Replace endAnimation with this:

```
@Override
    public void endAnimation(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {
        super.endAnimation(item);
        item.itemView.setTranslationY(0f);
    }
```

This will make sure that the holder is always returning to it's original position.

In your Adapter, add the following line to the onBindViewHolder method:

```
holder.itemView.setTranslationY(0f);
```

With the line above, I get a strange bug of the first item of another dataset being stuck in the background, but if you add a background that is the same color as the background of the RecyclerView to your items that bug is also fixed.

Sometimes it's very useful to write things down as they are to see the solution. Like this time it pointed me to the solution.